# How do I use itertools.product() in python to loop over multiple arrays?

Tags: python, tuples, product, python-itertools, cartesian-product

This is a part of my code:

```
m,n=list(map(int,input().split()))
for i in range(m):
    L=list(map(int,input().split()))
    if(i==0):
        K=L.copy()
        continue
    K=list(product(list(K),list(L)))
```

the input of the program would be:

4 """No.of arrays"""

2 5 3

3 7 4

1 5 3

3 5 1

I have used itertools.product to perform the cartesian product between the 4 arrays.

The output I get is of the form:
[(((2, 3), 5),1).....(((3,4),3),5)].
How can I refine my code in a such that I get an output of the form:
[(2,3,5,1).....(3,4,3,5)].

Comment: Add what you want to do and add sample input to question. So that we can work on it. you [edit] from here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Ch3sterR. I have added additional information for clarity.

Comment: Why do you use ``product``? Your desired output suggests you may want ``zip``. Can please provide enough expected output to clearly define what you actually want, i.e. include some intermediate values. Can you clarify how the entry ``2, 3, 5, 8`` comes to be? Your input does not have an ``8``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I didnt want to use zip because, I need to find the cartesian product between some user specified number of arrays(also with different sizes). I have edited my question to be even more clear. Since the number of the tuples obtained after using the product is 3^4, I have just shown some two entries of the output

Comment: So you want every possible tuple where you choose one item from each list?

Comment: @blueteeth Yes. Cartesian product between a number of lists, two at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
arrays = [[2, 5, 3], [3, 7, 4], [1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 1]]

list(product(*arrays))
```

Comment: I didnt want to use zip because, I need to find the cartesian product between some user specified number of arrays(also with different sizes). I have edited my question to be even more clear. Since the number of the tuples obtained after using the product is 3^4, I have just shown some two tuples of the output